# Altering formats from text file in python

Tags: python, list, text-files

I am trying to iterate through a text file that looks like this :

```
Funny Dogs | funny_dogs_video_id | #dog , #animal
Amazing Cats | amazing_cats_video_id | #cat , #animal
Another Cat Video | another_cat_video_id |  #cat , #animal
Life at Google | life_at_google_video_id |  #google , #career
Video about nothing | nothing_video_id |
```

I need to be able to print the file to look like this:

```
Funny Dogs (funny_dogs_video_id)  [#dog , #animal]
Amazing Cats ( amazing_cats_video_id )  [#cat , #animal]
Another Cat Video ( another_cat_video_id ) [ #cat , #animal]
Life at Google (life_at_google_video_id)  [#google , #career]
Video about nothing (nothing_video_id) []
```

I need to list all available videos in the format "title(video_id)[tag]"

My code so far:

```
def show_all_videos(self):
    print("Here's a list of all available videos: ")
    with open('/Users/Name/code-sample/python/src/videos.txt')as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        lines.sort()
        available_videos = ""
        for line in lines:
            available_videos += line
        print(available_videos)
```

However, my code outputs my file in the same format as the text file is already in.
Is there any suggestions how I can change the format of this code into my desired format?

Comment: Where in your code are you using the opened file `f`?

Comment: And where is ```lines``` ?

Comment: I've edited that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
with open("videos.txt") as f:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]

available_videos = ""
for line in lines:
    title, video, tags = [x.strip() for x in line.split("|")]
    available_videos += f"{title} ({video}) [{tags}]\n"

>>> print(available_videos)
Funny Dogs (funny_dogs_video_id) [#dog , #animal]
Amazing Cats (amazing_cats_video_id) [#cat , #animal]
Another Cat Video (another_cat_video_id) [#cat , #animal]
Life at Google (life_at_google_video_id) [#google , #career]
Video about nothing (nothing_video_id) []
```

Answer (score 0):

just split on `|`

perhaps as simple as

```py
with open("videos.txt") as fh_src, open(destination, "w") as fh_dest:
    for line in fh_src:
        title, video_id, tags = line.split("|")
        # rewrite line here, such as calling .strip() on the fields
        fh_dest.write(f"{title} ({video_id}) [{tags}]\n")
```

Comment: dont forget to strip() or you will receive it with spaces

Comment: fh_dest.write(f"{title.strip()} ({video_id. strip()}) [{tags.strip()}]\n")

Answer (score 0):

Split your line at `'|'` and print the data as you require.

```
for line in lines:
    title, video_id, tag = line.split('|')
    print(f'{title} ({video_id}) [{tag}]')
```